# Using application insights REST API for reading custom events

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

We have a custom event put in place on page which tracks the link clicks on given page to app insights. And with the REST API we would like to get the frequently accessed links from app insights.
How can we build the Query to get this analytics data, any sample on reading custom events available?

Thanks

Comment: This is now a feature of the updated App Insights in Azure. Do you still need help?

Answer (score 2):

if you open the Application Insights Analytics website for any resource, there's some "Common Queries" examples right on the front page.  one of them is called "Usage" and if you click it it will show you this one:

```
//What are the top 10 custom events of your application in the past 24 hours?
customEvents 
 | where timestamp >= ago(24h)
 | summarize dcount(user_Id), count() by name
 | top 10 by count_ 
 | render barchart
```

which:

1. queries `customEvents`,
2. filtering to the last 24 hours (`timestamp >= ago(24h)`),
3. does a summary of the distinct count of users (`dcount(user_Id)`) and the total number of events (`count()`), grouped by the event name (`by name`),
4. then filters to the top 10 by the _count field created from the summarization (`top 10 by count_`)
5. and then renders it as a bar chart (`render barchart`)

there are many other examples on the analytics home page as well.

**Edit to add:** You can easily query any custom properties or metrics that you send as well.  the `customDimensions` and `customMeasurements` fields in each event type are `json` typed fields, and if there's no spaces in the names, you can just use dot notation to grab values.  if the field has names/special characters, use brackets and quotes:

```
customEvents 
 | where timestamp >= ago(1h)
 | extend a = customDimensions.NameOfFieldWithNoSpacesOrSpecialCharacters
 | extend b = customDimensions["Field with spaces"]
 | extend duration = customMeasurements["Duration (ms)"]
 | project a, b, duration
 | limit 10
```

(you don't need to use `extend`, you can use the fields however you want this way, with `extend` or `project` or `summarize` or any other functions or anything else.  i just used `extend` for the example here.)

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for your inputs.
Have checked the analytics sample, We could not find a way to read the custom properties that we added to the custom events using the analytics usage query. Is there a way to read the custom data properties which we logged while logging the custom activity to app insight using analytics queries?

Thanks

Comment: you can definitely query custom properties.  `customDimensions` field holds custom properties (as json), `customMeasurements` field holds custom metrics (also json).  i updated the answer with an example.

Comment: John, Could you please help with sort syntax when I use summarize. I want to select the top 3 by the count of custom event properties with the above query.

Comment: if you want the top 3 by some count, you can use `| top 3 by duration desc` or whatever field you want instead of `limit 10`